# how to pjsua2 loop_fovever without quit?

Tags: pjsip, pjsua2

With pjsua2 document, demo code like this:

```
// Configure an AccountConfig
AccountConfig acfg;
acfg.idUri = "sip:test@pjsip.org";
acfg.regConfig.registrarUri = "sip:pjsip.org";
AuthCredInfo cred("digest", "*", "test", 0, "secret");
acfg.sipConfig.authCreds.push_back( cred );
// Create the account
MyAccount *acc = new MyAccount;
acc->create(acfg);
// Here we don't have anything else to do..
pj_thread_sleep(10000);
// Delete the account. This will unregister from server
delete acc;
// This will implicitly shutdown the library
return 0;
```

It's use `pj_thread_sleep(10000)` to avoid app quit.

and I need pjsua2 app always running as server side, should't exit.

so that function should i use instead of `pj_thread_sleep`, such "loop_forever", thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Endpoint.libHandleEvents`](https://www.pjsip.org/docs/book-latest/html/reference.html?highlight=libhandleevents#_CPPv4N2pj8Endpoint15libHandleEventsEj). I use the Python binding but the API should be the same. Here is an example.

```py
try:
    while True:
        ep.libHandleEvents(60_000)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    logger.info("Exiting. Received interrupt signal.")
finally:
    ep.libDestroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just block program exit sloved my problem.

```
while (true) {
  std::getchar();
}
```